# What Ubuntu should I install?

Tags: distro-recommendation

My purpose is to have an OS like unmanage vps/server for web hosting out there. For Learning in my own space before jumping to online!

I have a notebook Dell Vostro 3460 with i5 3230M. I have Window 7 Ultimate 32bit currently running. I want to know: What Ubuntu should I install for my purpose (Desktop or Server)? Should I use 32bit or 64bit? Which version is suitable for newbie start learning like me (12.04.3 LTS or 13.10)?

Thanks in advanced! Please, easy on me as I'm just starting out!

Answer (score 0):

With a machine that new, a **64 bit** OS is the right choice for almost all users.

Since you are planning on installing Ubuntu on your laptop, the **desktop** version is the way to go. That will give you a desktop environment to get started with. While most servers don't use graphical programs, for someone new to Linux an OS with only a command line can be very intimidating.

I'd recommend Ubuntu **12.04** for your laptop, since that version is [known to work with very little problems](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201202-10527/). Also, if you should later decide to try the latest version, it's only an upgrade away, no need to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Dell Vostro 3460, by standard, uses Windows 7 64-bit edition. So I recommend you download a 64-bit flavour of Ubuntu.

If you want to run Ubuntu on you PC for a long time, use 12.04 LTS which is the most stable version yet. But unless you want a constant refresh, get yourself 13.10, which has 6-month support (nothing to do with license).

Comment: 13.10 has 9 months of support...